# Split String and Store in Array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a string that would always output in the following format, but with different lengths.

```
String s1= "['Aaaa', 'Eeee', 'Ffff', 'Cccc', 'Dddd']";
```

How to split this `string` and store the values in a n `array` of `strings`, I tried String.Split(), but I failed to catch the inner values.

Do you think regular expressions could help???

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser as you should?

Comment: `String.Split()` it does not exist. Can you post your code so we make sure you really tried something?

Comment: what is your String ?? is s1 and s2 your original strings and you wanna split them such that your resulting array is {Aaaa, Eeee.....}??

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Perhaps `String#split(String)` was meant here

Comment: These look JSON encoded - why not just use a JSON decoder which will turn them into an array?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov fixed already

Comment: To those mentioning a json parser - adding another jar to your classpath isn't always the answer.

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys then you could download the library as a source code ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried running it through `Split` with  the regex parameter as`"[\\[\\]\\', ]"`

Basically any of  `[`,`]`,`,`,`'`, - more information [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is my code , Hope it will help

```
    String s1 = "['Aaaa', 'Eeee', 'Ffff', 'Cccc', 'Dddd']";
    String s2 = "['Aaaa', 'Eeee']";
    String[] xx = s1.substring(2, s1.length() - 2).split("', '");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   String s1= "['Aaaa', 'Eeee', 'Ffff', 'Cccc', 'Dddd']";

       String[]  array = s1.split(",");
       for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
       {
           System.out.println(array[i]);
       }
```

Comment: Close. What about the brackets?

Comment: Can be replaced. i write for the split only. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

**Suppose**

```
 String s = "dog cat cat dog";
```

//Now you want to split this String and save in to String[] (String Array)

```
String[] t= s.split(" ");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
```

// output you will get as ["dog", "cat", "cat", "dog"];